# Client CPU goes almost 100% when stop service

Tags: wcf, winapi, windows-services

We have a service which is hosted as a Windows service. `netTcpBinding` with message security type without reliable session.

On the client side we have a proxy collection cached in a list as channel creation and dispose is costly operations. My client is connecting to server and getting the data from server.

Now if I stop the server, then the CPU jumps up. The worker thread which consumes CPU is for the code execution of

```
void System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, NativeOverlapped *)
```

When i dispose all the proxies the client application CPU consumption becomes none. I need to know how we can fix up this issue on the WCF.

Answer (score 0):

One question is why are you having collection of proxy's on client for single wcf service. Say you have 20 proxies and WCF Service instancing is *per-session* then it will create 20 instances of service on your server each having memory allocated to it. If you are having per-call (which is default) then you will have even more instances. Instead of having list of proxies cant you reuse one proxy.

I suppose when you are stopping service, cpu has to clean(garbage collect) too many instances of service in short time hence it jumps.

Unless you do not close proxies their respective instances on server wont be released.Try making instancing Singleton.